# Change sync server in windows 10 sync center

Tags: windows-10, offline-files, sync-center

I have a user whos offline files are not synced with the files server. The offline files are trying to connect to old file server (not on network any more). All the data (since 1 year)is now stored on the offline cache.
How do i change the sync offline to the current file server? I have to do this without losing the offline data.
old: \servernamealias\user$
Current: \servernamealias01\user$
Thank you

Comment: If the data is properly on the local machine, just end the sync to the old server, restart and make a new sync for offline files on the new server.

Comment: Data is in offline cache. But i'm not sure of the location of the offline location is in CSC folder. However i have asked the user to copy data to local drive folder.

Comment: Since the old server is offline, that is about the only way. That is what we have done in like circumstances.

Comment: So after backup, we just copy paste it to new file server. Then start sync with new server i.e after i have reset the offline cache.

Comment: Yes. That should work fine. Put the data in its Server home and set up a new Sync for this data.

Comment: okay. Thank you.

Comment: If I summarize my steps in an answer, will you find that helpful?

Comment: Yes. Sure. That will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I have done that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the host file in system32/drivers/etc/host with ipaddress of new file server and hostname of old file server. After restart, ran the sync offline files in Sync Center. The sync worked.